# SqlDataReader GetOrdinal with same name

Tags: c#, sqldatareader

is need to use `GetOrdinal` from the `SqlDataReader` but my query is with joins and contains the same field name multiple times.
So I try

```
SELECT a.Id, b.Id FROM table1 AS a ...
```

but GetOrdinal seems don`t understand the schema alias...`GetOrdinal('a.Id')`
throws an Exception... is there anyway to archive this?

Comment: Why do you need the name at all? You could use `reader.GetInt32(0)` and `reader.GetInt32(1)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Give an alias name in your query

```
SELECT a.Id As EmployeeID, b.Id as ManagerId FROM table1 AS a ..
```

Now you can use the Alias names in your code to read the value

```
var employeeIdIndex = reader.GetOrdinal("EmployeeID")
```

Comment: That is what I try to avoid :)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid that ?

Comment: but with the schema alias it was unique in a way, so its a bit more work todo

Comment: @Sebastian I Think you are trying to address the problem in a wrong way. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I have a statement like the way I describe, in the application I know the schema alias and the field name so I need the index of the column to get the data. But it seems that isn't possible in this way

Answer (score 5):

I had this same question myself and I found the two common answers were:

- Alias the field in your SQL
- Use the integer index for the column

I didn't like either of these options so I created a third: GetNthOrdinal.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;

public static class SqlDataReaderExtensions
{
    public static int GetNthOrdinal(this SqlDataReader reader, string columnName, int nthOccurrence = 1)
    {
        // Get the schema which represents the columns in the reader
        DataTable schema = reader.GetSchemaTable();

        // Find all columns in the schema which match the name we're looking for.
        // schema is a table and each row is a column from our reader.
        var occurrences = schema.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(r => string.Equals((string)r["ColumnName"], columnName, StringComparison.Ordinal));

        // Get the nthOccurrence.  Will throw if occurrences is empty.
        // reader.GetOrdinal will also throw if a column is not present, but you may want to
        // have this throw a more meaningful exception
        var occurrence = occurrences.Skip(nthOccurrence - 1).First();

        // return the ordinal
        return (int)occurrence["ColumnOrdinal"];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
reader.GetNthOrdinal("Id", 2);
```

It's important to note that nth occurrence is not 0-based; it starts at 1.

Comment: Coming back to this a couple years later, I want to state that the main reason aliasing wasn't an option for me was that I did not have the ability to modify the SQL.  Given the ability to modify the SQL query, aliasing is the best option.